# Create new component and inherit styles from styled-component

Tags: javascript, styled-components, emotion

```
const Button = styled.button`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
`    

const ButtonHref = styled.a`
  ${Button}
`
```

So I have two styled-components. I want to inherit 'Button' styles but create another tag. I use react-emotion. How can I do this?

Comment: did the below answer your question?

Answer (score 40):

There are a few options here, using composition, styled components, or with props. The second option is probably what you want, but I've provided two other options as well.

**1. Using composition**

```
const baseButton = css`
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
`

const fancyButton = css`
  background-color: red;
`

render() {

  return (
    <div>
      <button css={baseButton}></button>
     <button css={[baseButton, fancyButton]}></button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The second button will have the `baseButton` and `specialButton` styles.

Or...

```
const baseButton = css`
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
`

const fancyButton = css`
 ${baseButton};
 background-color: red;
`

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <button css={baseButton}></button>
     <button css={fancyButton}></button>
   </div>
 )
}
```

**2. Using styled components**

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
`
const Fancy = styled(Button)`
  background-color: red;
`

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>Button</Button>
      <Fancy>Fancy</Fancy>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This works for any component that accepts the `className` prop, which `button` does.

**3. Using `props`**

```
  const Button = styled.button`
    color: white;
    background-color: ${props => props.fancy ? 'red' : 'black'};
  `

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button>Button</Button>
        <Button fancy>Fancy</Button>
      </div>
    )
  )
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, OP wants to inherit the styles of `button` and applied them to `a`, your solutions work only for the same tag. I'm wondering if you can compose the styles of **different** tags

Comment: @Raftel I'm looking for the same, how did you overcome it?

Comment: @BluePie You may want to look at the `withComponent` - https://www.styled-components.com/

Comment: @BluePie I used the [`as` prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#as-prop)

Comment: @BrettDeWoody [As of styled-components v4 the withComponent API is now a candidate for deprecation](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#withcomponent). [as prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) seems good. thank you guys.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want an `a` that has the exact styles as your `Button` then you can do `<Button as=“a” />`

Comment: that's the correct answer! your can even do `<Button as={Anchor} />` where `Anchor` is another component.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add some custom css like this:

```
const ButtonBase = styled.button`
    // some css here
`

const SmallButtonCustom = `
    // some css here
`

const SmallButton = styled(ButtonBase)`
    ${SmallButtonCustom};
`
```